# Function composition not equal to manual derivation using chain rule

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule, function-and-relation-composition

Consider the following two functions $f,g$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
  f(k,p,x)&=kx^2p^{-1}
  \\
  g(k,m,x)&=2^mxk^{-1}\;\text{.}
\end{aligned}
$$

While both functions share the parameter $k$, they do **not** share $p,m$. The partial derivatives for both functions are:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla\,f=&
\bigg[\;\frac{\partial\,f}{\partial\,k}=x^2p^{-1},\;
\frac{\partial\,f}{\partial\,p}=-\frac{kx^2}{p^2},\;
\frac{\partial\,f}{\partial\,m}=0\;\bigg]^\top\;\text{, and for }g(x)\text{:}
\\[2em]
\nabla\,g=&
\bigg[\;\frac{\partial\,g}{\partial\,k}=-\frac{x2^m}{k^2},\;
\frac{\partial\,g}{\partial\,p}=0,\;
\frac{\partial\,g}{\partial\,m}=2^mx\log{(2)}k^{-1}\;\bigg]^\top\;\text{.}
\end{aligned}
$$

As can be seen, the partial derivatives for $\frac{\partial\,f}{\partial\,m}$ and $\frac{\partial\,g}{\partial\,p}$ are **$0$**, as the respective parameters do not exist in the respective functions.

**Problem**: The chain rule tells us that the derivative of the composite function $h(\dots,\,x)=f(g(x))$ is $h'(k,m,p,x)=f'(\dots,\;g(\dots,x))\times g'(\dots,\;x)$. Using the partial derivatives defined previously, this will lead to the partial derivatives for $p,m$ of the composite function $h(\dots,\,x)$ to also be zero.

However, if we do a manual substitution of $g(\dots,\,x)$ into $f(\dots,\,x)$, the resulting composite function becomes:

$$
\begin{aligned}
  h(k,m,p,x)&=f(k,p,g(k,m,x))
  \\
  &=\frac{k}{p}\times\bigg(\frac{x2^m}{k}\bigg)^2\;\text{,}
\end{aligned}
$$

which can obviously be derived for all parameters with a non-zero result. So where have I gone wrong here? Is the composition of $h(x)$ wrong?

**Addendum**: The partial derivatives of the composite function and the manual application of the chain rule for parameter $k$ are also not identical:

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \frac{\partial\,h}{\partial\,k}&=-\frac{4^mx^2}{k^2p}\;\text{, and using the chain rule it is:}
  \\
  \text{chain rule}&=-\frac{2^{3m}x^3}{k^4p}\;\text{.}
\end{aligned}
$$

I do not understand where the problem is, any directions are welcome!

Comment: You _say_ that something leads to $\partial h/\partial p=\partial h/\partial m=0$, but you don't explain why this is; in fact I see no reason either partial must vanish...

Comment: The partial derivatives for $h(k,m,p,x)$ are non-zero for parameters $p,m$. However -- and also check the addendum -- if I use the chain rule to compose and derive $h(x)$ instead, the result is different. And this is where I don't understand what's wrong :S

Comment: You made a mistake in the calculations. Since you don't show those calculations it's hard to see how anyone else can locate the error for you...